# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMarker When implementing GoogleMaps in my ios swift project

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

In my ios app whenever i try to create a marker from GMSMarker from google maps it starts showing the error "Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_GMSMarker". The problem is not only with marker but also with any instance of google maps i create.
I have tried Cleaning Project, Deleting Derived Data, Downgrading google Maps Version, Running Xcode with rosetta, Using an actual device, pod deintegrate and reinstall and adding and removing Google Maps from linked binaries still nothing works I am using cocoapods

Comment: Hello there! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community could help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your App may have some hidden dependencies. You need show more information about your problem